# Border and borderless div does not start at top baseline

Tags: html, css

How do I make the first and last div start at the top?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
div.arrow {
  border: none;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="box arrow">←</div>
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box arrow">→</div>
```

Comment: add vertical-align:top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `border: 10px solid lightgray;` to the `div.arrow`.

Because the only dimensional difference between `.box` and `div.arrow` is their border value.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 10px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.arrow {
    border: 10px solid lightgray;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="box arrow">←</div>
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box arrow">→</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `inline-flex` instead of `inline-box`. Add a padding on `div.arrow`, and you have your result:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  display: inline-flex;
  place-content: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: top
}
div.arrow {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="box arrow">←</div>
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box arrow">→</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

One way:

```
.box {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```